# Verify that that the initial value problem $y'=2\sqrt{y} \ \ , y(0)=0$ has two two different solutions $y_1(x)=x^2$ and $y_2(x)=0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Solving for the general solution, I got

$y(x)= x^2 +c_1x + \frac{{c_1}^2}{4}$

How is $y(x)=0$ a solution for $y'=2\sqrt{y}$  ?

Comment: Try plugging it in to the ODE! If $y(x) \equiv 0$  then $y'(x) \equiv 0$ ...  btw the ODE also has the solution $y(x) = 0$ for $x<0$ with $y(x) = x^2$ for $x>0$.

Comment: $y(x)= x^2 +c_1x + \frac{{c_1}^2}{4}$ doesn't satisfy $y(0)=0$ unless $c_1=0.$

Comment: Truth to be told, $y(x)=x^2$ does not satisfy $y'=2\sqrt y$ on any neighbourhood of $0$. But $y_a(x)=\begin{cases} 0&\text{if }x\le a\\ (x-a)^2&\text{if }x>a\end{cases}$ do for all $a\ge0$, though.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes there exist some solutions that are not particular cases of the general solution. These singular solutions can take place when uniqueness of a solution is not guaranteed from the usual conditions (here $f(x,y)=2\sqrt y$ fails to satisfy some condition; check the theorems you have to see which one).

In any case, for what I see you just are asked to check that these are indeed solutions for an IVP (I assume that $y=0$ is actually the condition $y(0)=0$. It should also be the case that the domain of $y$ is taken to be $[0,\infty)$ or something smaller, because otherwise $y_1$ won't be a solution.

If that is so, then you just have to see that
$$y_1(0)=0$$
(which is obvious)
and that
$$y_1'(x)=2\sqrt {y_1(x)}, \quad \forall x\in [0,\infty),$$
which is also true; then do the same for $y_2(x)=0$, which is straightforward.

Comment: I know I could check to see if this solution satisfies the uniqueness theorem by checking $D_y(x,y)$ is continuous in that neighborhood. Since $D_y(x,y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}$ I know that it is discontinuous for $y \le 0$. So $y(0)=0$ does not have a unique solution. What I wanted to know was how one would show that an initial condition of $y(x_0)=y_0$ does not have a unique solution without first testing to see if they satisfy those theorems. Because my professor stated that you should see right away that $y'=2\sqrt{y} has more than one solution for the IVP y(0)=0$.

Comment: It is precisely for what you have said. Since the problem comes for $y=0$, for any problem with $y(t_0)=0$ you will have that situation. Also, "you should see right away" that $y=0$ is a solution. When a professor says things like that, it's "right away" for him, not always for you.